# Client request for tensorflow serving gives error "Attempting to use uninitialized value fully_connected/biases"

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-serving, tensor

I created a LSTM RNN model for text classification on tensorflow and exported the savedModel successfully. I tested the model using savedModel CLI and everything seems to be working fine. However I am trying to create a client that can make a request and get a result. I have been following this [tensorflow serving inception example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/example) (more specifically [inception_client.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py)) for reference. This works well with the inception model but I am not sure how to change the request for my own model. How exactly should I change the request?

My signature and saving the model:

```
# Build the signature_def_map.
classification_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS: classification_inputs},
    outputs={
      signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
          classification_outputs_classes,
    },
  method_name=signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)

legacy_init_op = tf.group(
    tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
#add the sigs to the servable
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
            classification_signature
    },
    assets_collection=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.ASSET_FILEPATHS),
    legacy_init_op=tf.group(assign_filename_op))



print ("added meta graph and variables")

builder.save()
print("model saved")
```

The model takes in `inputs_` as the input which is a list of list of numbers ( [[1,3,4,5,2]] ).

```
inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="input_ints")
```

How I am using the savedModel CLI (returns right results):

```
$ saved_model_cli run --dir ./python2_SavedModelFinalInputInts --tag_set serve --signature_def 'serving_default' --input_exprs inputs='[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2634, 758, 938, 579, 1868, 1894, 24, 651, 572, 32, 1847, 232]]'
```

More information about the savedModel:

```
$ saved_model_cli show --dir ./python2_prediction_SavedModelFinalInputInts --all

MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_INT32
    shape: (-1, -1)
    name: inputs/input_ints:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['outputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (1, 1)
    name: predictions/fully_connected/Sigmoid:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

How I am trying to create a request in the client code:

```
        request1 = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
        request1.model_spec.name = 'mnist'
        request1.model_spec.signature_name = signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY
     request1.inputs[signature_constants.PREDICT_INPUTS].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(input_nums, shape=[1,100],dtype=tf.int32))

    response = stub.Predict(request1,1.0)

   result_dict = { 'Analyst Rating': str(response.message) }
    return jsonify(result_dict)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[2017-11-29 19:03:29,318] ERROR in app: Exception on /analyst_rating [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "restApi.py", line 91, in post
    response = stub.Predict(request,1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 309, in __call__
    self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 195, in _blocking_unary_unary
    raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, details="Attempting to use uninitialized value fully_connected/biases
     [[Node: fully_connected/biases/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@fully_connected/biases"], _output_shapes=[[1]], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fully_connected/biases)]]")
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2017 19:03:29] "POST /analyst_rating HTTP/1.1" 500 -
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
```

## Update:

Changing the signature of the model from a classification signature to a prediction signature seemed to work. I also changed the legacy_init_op to legacy_init_op as defined from assign_filename_op which I was using for Assets organization initially.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the model signature from classification to a prediction signature seemed to return results.

```
prediction_signature = (tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={signature_constants.PREDICT_INPUTS: prediction_inputs},
    outputs={signature_constants.PREDICT_OUTPUTS: prediction_outputs},
    method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
#add the sigs to the servable
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
            prediction_signature
    },
    # assets_collection=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.ASSET_FILEPATHS),
    legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
```

I am not entirely sure how the client request should be for a model with classification signature or why it was not working.

(If anyone has an explanation, I will select that as the correct answer.)